# Scheme: Using objects to modify lists

Tags: list, object, scheme

I'm trying to return the max element in a list using objects. I want to try and find a way to do so without simply getting the maximum element of the list, and instead I'm trying to check the first two elements against each other to get the max, and then check the max of the first two elements against the next element and so on.

Here's what I currently have:

```
(define (stat-set)
  (let ((L '(10 2 5)))

(define (largest)
  (define (current-max)
    (begin
      (set! current-max
            (max (car L) (cadr L)))          
      current-max))
  (current-max))

(lambda (method)
  (cond ((eq? method 'largest) largest)))))

(define n (stat-set))
(n 'largest))
```

I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the line

```
(max (car L) (cadr L)))
```

but I'm not sure how to fix it. When I try using largest on a list of '(2 10), it returns 10. However, if I were to use largest on a list of '(5 2 10) it returns 5, while I would like it to return 10 still. I know this is because I'm only comparing the first two elements by using car and cadr, but am unsure as to how to store the maximum of '(2 10) so I can compare it to '(5).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If the `largest` procedure is the only one that is not working correctly, you should consider removing everything else, as it is not relevant to the problem. On another note, you should give an example of the output your getting, and the output you _want_ to get.

Comment: Note that Scheme has only one namespace. You are defining a no argument procedure that sets it's own binding to a list.  You are accessing `L` but I'm not seing it as an argument anywhere. Is this a magic global variable? If so you will only be getting the largest of the two very first elements of that global. Usually one finds the largest element in a list by iterating it with recursion while holding on the largest value that is returned in the end. No `set!` required.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to accomplish: Define a SCHEME object that maintains a set of numbers. Your object should have methods that correspond to
• largest, which should return the largest element
Implement the set as a standard SCHEME list, and
return a dispatcher that provides access to your methods via a token.
Important amplification. Your stat-set methods that implement largest should use only a constant amount of computation to determine their return value: specifically,
the amount of time they take to return should not depend on the size of the set.

Comment: Scheme has no objects. Which oo system are you using?

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Scheme does, but it's called closures.

Comment: @Sylwester [It is known](http://people.csail.mit.edu/gregs/ll1-discuss-archive-html/msg03277.html)